# Accessing scripts from a vps

Tags: node.js, flutter, api, vps

I have a mobile application built in flutter , and a few node.js scripts that are supposed to be executed on the server (a vps) on occurrence of an event within the app. How do I store those scripts on the server and access it in like an api or any other method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours. These are way to few details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.